# Khmer fonts in VF page for PDF rendering

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, html, pdf

I am not sure why Khmer fonts are not supported in Visualforce page. The below are the fonts that are supported by VF page.

| Font Type | Fonts |
| --- | --- |
| Arial Unicode MS | Arial Unicode MS |
| Helvetica | sans-serif, SansSerif, Dialog |
| Times | serif, Times |
| Courier | monospace, courier, monospaced, dialoginput |

- It seems like of all the fonts mentioned below, only Arial Unicode font supports Visualforce PDF rendering as per the article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321277&type=1&mode=1
- I tried to test it myself with a sample code and it worked when you don’t render it as pdf and just render it in a page. When I add `renderAs = pdf`, it doesn’t display the Khmer characters. I tried Thai characters with `font-family` as Arial Unicode MS and it works in both in a page and in pdf.
- Also, web fonts are not supported when you render it as pdf.

**In a Web Page** - Khmer fonts are displayed

[image: In a Web page]

**In PDF** - Khmer fonts are not displayed

[image]

Here is my code for you to try it out:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" renderAs="pdf">
    <head>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Khmer&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <style>
            body {
            font-family: 'Khmer ';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        ឲ្យខ្លាច <br/>
        This is a sample page: API version 28.0
        
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Please let me know if there are any alternatives to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are only *specifically* allowed to use the named fonts in the list (that's just four fonts). You can't use any other font, even if they may happen to be a "serif" font. You are not allowed to use custom web fonts, either. I do find it interesting that it doesn't render *at all*, but this isn't exactly surprising. Use only the allowed fonts to avoid rendering problems.

If you want to share code, you should be able to specify a fallback font:

```
    <style>
        body {
        font-family: 'Khmer','sans-serif';
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm) from which the above font table derive explicitly states

> Web fonts aren’t supported when the page is rendered as a PDF file. You can use web fonts in your Visualforce pages when they’re rendered normally.

The PDF engine used to render Visualforce pages does not support a wide variety of modern Web technologies. If you need sophisticated PDF rendering that goes above and beyond those capabilities, consider another solution:

- Building an off-platform application on Heroku or another solution, where you can make use of PDF generation libraries in your language of choice. ([Safe harbor]: Salesforce Functions, formerly Evergreen, may be a strong candidate for this use case when it is GA).
- Generating the PDF file on the front end using a JavaScript PDF library.
- Purchasing an AppExchange document generation solution that offers broader font support.